# Android CursorAdapter.changeCursor causes ListView scrolling to behave strangely

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

**What I'm Trying to Accomplish**

I have an implementation of CursorAdapter that is displaying content from a SQLite database in a ListView. The controls in the list view allow users to toggle a value in the database.

**The Problem**

After records in the database are updated, the Cursor used by the CursorAdapter implementation needs to be updated with the new values. According to Android documentation, the best way to do this is to load a new cursor and call changeCursor on the CursorAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29.

```
// Some pseudo code
public void onSomeEvent() { 
    // update the database record
    toggleRecord();
    // load a new cursor
    Cursor newCursor = loadNewCursorFromDb();
    // Load the newCursor into the CursorAdapter which drives the ListView
    MyCursorAdapter adapter = (MyCursorAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
    // now the ListView scrolls strangely...
}
```

After this changeCursor call, a nasty side effect causes the ListView's scrolling to behave strangely. A "fling" causes the list to scroll and the scrolling will not stop until it grinds to a halt. Normal behavior would allow a user to stop the list from scrolling by touching the scrolling list or scroll this list further by performing another fling. The ListView behaves normally before the changeCursor call is executed.

How can I stop this nasty side effect?!

Edit: I should have mentioned that I'm using android.widget.CursorAdapter and targeting API level 7 (Eclair).

Comment: That sounds weird, I'm not having this issue. But: I'm not using CursorAdapter, but SimpleCursorAdapter, and I'm not using the one from the android.support.v4 package but from android.widget. Maybe you can try one of them? Sorry I can't help any further.

Comment: For this use case, I think SimpleCursorAdapter may be too "simple". I need to bind events to widgets in the list item at the time the list item is created- can I do that with a SimpleCursorAdapter?